# I want to compare list of two cities and if list B cities are not present in list A then should append in list A using python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

```
A=['mumbai','delhi','jaipur']
B=['mumbai','kolkata','pune']
```

> I want to compare list A and list B and if list B cities are not in list A then we should able to append those cities in list A

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do the same but not by using the for loop.

```
difference_between_lists = list(set(B) - set(A))
A += difference_between_lists
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop through list B and check if the item in list B is in list A. If it is, don't do anything, if it isn't, append it to list A.

```
for i in B:
    if not i in A:
        A.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using list comprehension

```
C = [i for i in B if not i in A]
print(A+C)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sets and do the union.

```
setA = set(A)
setB = set(B)
print(setB.union(setA))
```